# WebSQL and jQuery - DB vanishes on refresh

Tags: web-sql

I have a very simple app (the beginnings of a larger app) which does one thing at this point. All it does is create a new database and table and inserts a single row of data. The problem is, when I hit "refresh" on the browser, the data and table is gone. I'm using Chrome and the developer inspection tools to see the data in the WebSQL tables.

Anyone had this before? What am I doing wrong? I thought the point of HTML5 was persistant data so even on refresh the DB should stick around. Am I wrong on that?

Here's my simple code:

**index.html**

```
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <button id="deviceReady">Device Ready</button>
    <button id="resetSQL">Reset SQL</button>
  </div>
```

**Then some jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#deviceReady").click(function(){
    alert("device ready");
    initDB();
  });

  $("#resetSQL").click(function () {
    var db = openDatabase(dbName, dbTitle, dbVersion, dbMaxSize);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS creds');
      tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo');
    });
  });
});
```

**Actual DB Stuff**

```
function initDB() {
  var db = openDatabase(dbName, dbTitle, dbVersion, dbMaxSize);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS creds (id unique, usr, psw)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO creds (id, usr, psw) VALUES (1, "none", "none")');
  });
}
```

So all I do is open the webpage, click "Device Ready" button to run the `initDB` function. The data shows up in the database correctly, but then when I refresh, its gone.

Answer (score 0):

You are right data should stick around unless you run drop table or delete query.  So in this code only place you have that is reset click handler, try to comment that out and see if the data is retained.  Maybe somehow that click event is triggered instead of just registering.

Comment: You are right (about the data sticking around). What I ended up doing is just continueing with my development assuming the data was, in fact, still there. Sure enough, it was. However, when hitting refresh, it would still make it look like the data was gone, but it was still there. It made for very challenging debugging since I couldn't view the data if I hit refresh, even though it was there.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't show the databases unless you opened them via `openDatabase`. The databases are still there, they are just hidden. You have to call the function to show up your database indeed.